# A question from a competitive examination (Topic: Elementary Set Theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

How do I approach this problem. If possible, please give a hint first and then the solution (as a spoiler).

Comment: If you are on competitive exams, you surely have a first idea ...  Why don't you share it with us, before asking us to do the job for you ? This is a basic principle on this site : we help people who begin by working by themselves...

Comment: For example, how might you want to maximise $m$?

Comment: @Mathematician42 I solved the inequality m(m+1)/2<100. The maximum value of m came out to be 13. So, is this the answer?

Comment: The smallest total number of elements in three nonempty disjoint sets all of which have different cardinalities would be $6$ and are comprised of sets of size $1$, $2$, and $3$ respectively.  You can prove this as well, consider three sets $A_1,A_2,A_3$ with $|A_1|<|A_2|<|A_3|$.  Then $|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|\geq |A_1|+|A_2|+3\geq\dots\geq 6$ (*make sure you understand why*).  What can you say about the respective sizes of the sets in general?  What then can you say about the minimum number of elements needed to make up fifteen disjoint sets all of different cardinalities?  How about fourteen?

Comment: Arrange the values $|A_1|;,,,, |A_m|$ in increasing order as  $x_1,...,x_n.$ Then $x_1\geq 1$, and if $  1\leq j<m$ and $x_j\geq j$ then $x_{j+1}\geq x+x_j\geq 1+j$. So each $x_j\geq j$  by induction on $j $.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have solved the question. Can someone write the solution as an answer so that future viewers can benefit from it?

Comment: @MrigankaParasar You are more than welcome to answer your own question.